# when adding a table to my dbo.view I don't get the entire view

Tags: sql-server-2012, view

here is the code for my view that calls all rows from the tables:

```
SELECT
dbo.Purchase_Order.Purchase_Order_ID, dbo.Purchase_Order.Purchase_Order_Number, dbo.Purchase_Order.Purchase_Order_Date, dbo.Purchase_Order.Special_Instructions, dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Qty_Ordered, dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Work_Order_Number, 
dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Part_Discount, dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Part_List_Price, dbo.Vendor.Vendor_Name, dbo.Ship_Method.Ship_Method, 
dbo.Ship_Method.Ship_Method_Acct_Number, dbo.Inventory.Part_Number, dbo.Inventory.Part_Description, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Address, 
dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_City, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_State_Prov, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Zip_Country_Code, 
dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Phone_800, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Phone_Local, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Address_2, 
dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Country, dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_Fax
FROM
dbo.Purchase_Order INNER JOIN
dbo.Purchase_Order_Items ON dbo.Purchase_Order.Purchase_Order_ID = dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Purchase_Order_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.Vendor ON dbo.Purchase_Order.Vendor_ID = dbo.Vendor.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.Ship_Method ON dbo.Purchase_Order.Ship_Method_ID = dbo.Ship_Method.Ship_Method_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.Inventory ON dbo.Purchase_Order_Items.Part_Number_ID = dbo.Inventory.Part_Number_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.Vendor_Location ON dbo.Vendor.Vendor_ID = dbo.Vendor_Location.Vendor_ID
```

Then I add another table and then I only get 2 rows in my view when there should be 115 rows:

the following line is added the end of the FROM statement

```
dbo.Customer ON dbo.Purchase_Order.Customer_ID = dbo.Customer.Customer_ID
```

any ideas as to why?  is there a limit to how many tables can be in a view?

thanks for looking 
Dave

Thanks for the help from all the attitude.  for those that would really like to know the answer, this line fixed the join problem.

```
dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer_Ship.Customer_ID = dbo.Customer.Customer_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
```

Comment: There is a thing called "aliases". I've heard it's good for making queries readable.

Comment: As for your problem, it's rather obvious. Some of the rows in `Purchase_Order` do not have a `Customer_ID` recorded (they have `NULL`). You can use `LEFT JOIN Customer ...` instead and the result will go back to 115 rows.

Comment: even if Purchase_Order.Customer_ID is null the rest of the rows in the  table shouldn't be eliminated in the view should it?  I will try the LEFT JOIN right after my meeting

Comment: I think you need to understand the basic concepts of `JOIN`s

Comment: why have I been down voted?  I thought this site is to get help and learn something.  I have been studying the concepts of JOIN and I am sure that I will figure it out.  it truly amazes me how much attitude there is on these sites.  this is why I very seldomly ask anything here.  when I created the VIEW I was using the designer in SQL Server by adding tables to the VIEW and choosing the fields that I would like to display.  you are correct about me not knowing a few things like the concept of JOIN but studying and the comment on "aliases" doesn't help at all.  Could you demonstrate aliases?

Comment: I have spent a bit of time on `JOIN` and have learned a lot of stuff and what I have learned is pretty cool.  The location of what helped me the most is at [StackOverflow by many members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins).  This was very helpful in the event someone else is having trouble like I did.  Now I guess I will see what I can find about "aliases".  Since this really isn't a place for getting help.  Very disappointed.

Comment: You were likely down voted because basic SQL questions are not on topic for this site. Those should be asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: there is so much attitude on Stack Overflow that I am not allowed to ask questions any more, no matter how I might try to repair my questions.

Answer (score 0):

after additional research I discovered that the real answer for my situation was the use of `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`  like this:

```
dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer_Ship.Customer_ID = dbo.Customer.Customer_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
```

my last comment also has a link to the page that helped me out the most